# How to change TeamCity data directory?

Tags: linux, teamcity, redhat

How to change data directory path for existing TeamCity server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should stop TeamCity server, move existing TeamCity data directory to a new location, let TeamCity server know about new data directory using /conf/teamcity-startup.properties file (since 9.1 version) or TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH environment variable (for more details see this [section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/TeamCity+Data+Directory#TeamCityDataDirectory-LocationoftheTeamCityDataDirectory)). 
Actually you can use instructions for [Copying TeamCity server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=54334889#HowTo...-CreateaCopyofTeamCityServerwithAllData), but skip Installation and database copy steps.

Comment: Getting TeamCity server startup error

The Data Directory contains files or directories that don't belong to TeamCity.

Comment: How did you configure TeamCity Data directory? Could you please list the content of the specified TeamCity Data Directory?

Comment: data folder new path is `/home/.BuildServer/` .
teamcity folder under `/home` dir .
I tried to change the TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH environment variable as below :
`export TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH=/home/.BuildServer/`

Comment: I have add this line to conf/teamcity-startup.sh file
`**TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH=/home/.BuildServer/**`

Its Work , Thanks :)